# JQuery select each parent, grab height of child1 and set child2 to child1 height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, height, responsive

So I have a php script to generate news/case posts from a database which repeats the following HTML

```
    <a href='/post/placeholder'>
  <div class='col nopadding col12-12 counter'>
    <div class='col col6-12 vheight'>
      <h2>placeholder</h2>
      <p>placeholder</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col col6-12 nopadding varheight '>
      <div class='imagewrapper'>
        <img src='/public/images/images/placeholder.jpg' />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

I'm wanting to select each 'counter' class, and have .vheight's height stored in a variable so that .varheight (the image) will always be the same height responsively.

I currently have this JQuery

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  $( ".counter" ).each(function() {
    var $counter = $(this).next('.vheight').outerHeight(true);
    $(this).next(".varheight").css("height", $counter);
  });
});

$(window).load(function () {
  $( ".counter" ).each(function() {
    var $counter = $(this).next('.vheight').outerHeight(true);
    $(".varheight").css("height", $counter);
  });
});
```

I can't seem to get it to work and have had a look around at other similar answers on SO.

Here's the test dev link so you can see how it will be looking

http://d53.6bdv.ws/cases

Comment: I think you should be using `.find('.vheight')` instead of `.next('.vheight')` since `.vheight` is a child of `.counter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are selecting wrong element by find, try this instead:

```
$(window).resize(function () {
  $( ".counter" ).each(function() {
    var $counter = $('.vheight', this).outerHeight(true);
    $('.vheight', this).css("height", $counter);
  });
});
```

Do the same selection on the load function => `$('your next element', this)`

Comment: You are welcome. I remember that I also had a hard time in the beginning to figure out how to chain elements with this before I found that it is possible like this: $('your next element', this)

Answer (score 2):

try and take a look at this if this is something that you want done and we could try to make changes if it does not suite your needs.

```js
$('.counter').each(function(){
  var myHieght = $(this).find('.vheight').height();
  $(this).find('.varheight').height(myHieght);
})
```

```css
a{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  float: left;
  width:250px;
} 
.varheight{
  position:relative
}
.imagewrapper{
  position:aboslute;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="http://google.com">
<div class='col nopadding col12-12 counter'>
    <div class='col col6-12 vheight'>
      <h2>placeholder</h2>
      <p>placeholder</p>
      <h2>placeholder</h2>
      <p>placeholder</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col col6-12 nopadding varheight '>
      <div class='imagewrapper'>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>

<a href="http://google.com">
<div class='col nopadding col12-12 counter'>
    <div class='col col6-12 vheight'>
      <h2>placeholder</h2>
      <p>placeholder</p>
    </div>
    <div class='col col6-12 nopadding varheight '>
      <div class='imagewrapper'>
        <img src="data:image/png;base64,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">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: I've tried the above and nothing much has changed, the issue is that each blog post needs to have height auto and not set absolutely by defining a height.

Comment: The Jquery is targeting one class and storing that height amount and not clearing/changing it for each .counter class for some reason

Comment: you could see if the image at the bottom changes when you change the contents of 1 vheight and you would see that varheight would be same size as to vheight

Answer (score 0):

Use find() instead of next()

```
$( ".counter" ).each(function() {
    var $counter = $(this).find('.vheight').outerHeight(true);
    $(this).find(".varheight").css("height", $counter);
});
```